# Dns not resolve for Subdomain in Route 53 From Parent Domain in Different Registrar

Tags: subdomain, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, cname, serverless-framework

I'm creating serverless application in nodejs env using aws lambda.
I need to add custom domain in API Gateway. 
Domain (lets say example.com) is registered with domain.com and hosted with other company. 
Parent domain (example.com) is working fine with other hosting company.
Now I want to add its subdomain (api.example.com) **in route 53** (aws)

1. I've created Hosted Zone in Route 53 with name example.com (Parent domain)
2. NS and SOA records are created automatically.
3. Cname api.example.com in **route 53** points to cloudfront url
4. **In domain.com** i've added cname for api.example.com that point to cloudfront url

I know dns can take upto 48 hours to resolve.
I've also seen WHM , cname can also be added there but i didn't touch there.

please help.

---

Update #1

I've done as deceze described in the answer section. below are the screenshots

[screenshot of NS-Record entered in my Parent Domain Registrar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gei37.jpg)

[Subdomain route53 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU3ts.png)

[I have some doubts on this nameserver section (in my parent domain registrar) , may be it has some effect on NS-record as the default nameservers not used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlPLj.jpg)

its has been around 20 hours , still not worked. 
Any Suggestions.

Comment: What does *domain.com* have to do with *example.com*? Nothing, as far as I can tell. You need to point the NS record of *example.com* to the AWS DNS servers at your registrar.

Comment: domain.com is a registrar of example.com

Comment: So, *example.com* already exists and is registered at ExampleNIC and there are existing DNS server for *example.com*? And you can edit records in that existing DNS record and are trying to set up *api.example.com* as a new subdomain with its own DNS servers, yes?

Comment: example.com already exists and is registered at ExampleNIC - **YES**
there are existing DNS server for example.com - **YES**
And you can edit records in that existing DNS record - **YES**
trying to set up api.example.com as a new subdomain with its own DNS servers - **MAY BE**

Comment: Well, either you manage *api.example.com* using the existing nameserver records, or you manage *api.example.com* as a delegated subzone using different nameservers. Your choice.

Comment: I just want subdomain of Parent Domain to register with AWS Route 53

Answer (score 1):

The authorative nameserver for *example.com* needs to delegate authority for *api.example.com* to the AWS nameservers. Which means, `NS` records for *api.example.com* containing the authoritive AWS nameservers for *api.example.com* need to be in the record of *example.com*.

- create the zone `api.example.com` in Route 53
- set its `A` record to point to your CloudFront distribution

Now you have a bunch of nameservers which are the authority for *api.example.com.* Now you just need to officially delegate authority for that subzone:

- create `NS` records for `api.example.com` pointing at your AWS nameservers in the existing `example.com` records

The lookup works like this from a client's perspective:

1. → *rootnameserver*, where's `api.example.com`?
   ← `NS` for `com` is `1.2.3.4`
2. → *1.2.3.4*, where is `api.example.com`?
   ← `NS` for `example.com` is `2.3.4.5` (your existing DNS server)
3. → *2.3.4.5*, where is `api.example.com`?
   ← `NS` for `api.example.com` is `3.4.5.6` (this is the delegation)
4. → *3.4.5.6*, where is `api.example.com`?
   ← `A` for `api.example.com` is `4.5.6.7` (this is your Route 53 record)

Comment: 1) I need to create api.example.com hosted zone **(NOT example.com)**
2) create A record points to CloudFront
3) In Domain.com where my parent domain (example.com) registered , add NS records points AWS nameserver.

Comment: As I said, yes. :)

Comment: I do not need to create CName record in my Parent Domain.

Comment: No. If you did that, that would mean your parent domain already manages records for *api.example.com* (which is also a possibility). If you want different Route 53 servers to manage that subdomain, you merely refer all lookups about that subdomain to those Route 53 servers using an `NS` entry.

Comment: ok i'll come back to this post , if I face any problem or solved.

Comment: As you can see from my given example, a client will ask each server directly for the answer it wants to have. If the server knows, it will answer. If it doesn't know but has an `NS` entry which gets close, it will respond with that. So the nameservers for *example.com* could manage *api.example.com* directly if they so chose.